# Why can't I find the Dockerfile?

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm making a Python (Django) and MySQL project.
After creating some files, I get an error when I run the command.

docker-compose up -d

`ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile`

Why am I getting an error when I have a Dockerfile in the current directory?

```
MYAPP
-django
--__init__.py
--asgi.py
--settings.py
--urls.py
--wsgi.py

-docker-compose.yml
-Dockerfile
-manage.py
-requirement.txt
-wait-for-in.sh
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/django
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: django
      MYSQL_DATABASE: django
      MYSQL_USER: django
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: django
  web:
    build: django
    command: sh -c "./wait-for-it.sh db:3306; python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/django
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/django
WORKDIR /var/www/django
ADD requirements.txt /var/www/django/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /var/www/django/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
web:
    build: django
```

is a shortcut for

```
web:
    build:
        context: django
```

and this means, the Docker image is built in the django directory. The Dockerfile should be placed there. Same with manage.py, requirement.txt and wait-for-in.sh.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
web:
  build:
    context: ./django/
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
web:
  build:
    context: ./django/
    dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: >
      sh -c "./wait-for-it.sh db:3306; python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```